# Resolving dependencies in filters in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, unity-container, filter

I'm using Unity as a IoC container in my MVC2 project, and I was wondering if there was a way to resolve property dependencies inside my filters from a class that extends the DefaultControllerFactory (I've resolved all of the dependencies in my controllers this way). I know I can resolve them by extending the ControllerActionInvoker, and creating a custom controller base, but then every controller would have to extend that base. I would like to avoid this if possible.
Btw. the problem occurred while I was trying to modularize my project with portable areas, and I couldn't pass the unity's container instance across projects. (if anyone knows how to use Unity with portable areas that would help also :-)).